# Why is SSMS unable to connect to local SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server

I have installed both SQL Server 2019 and SSMS 2018.

SQL Server is configured with following parameters:

- Shared memory: enabled
- TCP/IP: enabled
- Named Pipes: enabled

When I try to connect from SSMS to the local server, I get the following error:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to SQL-SERVER-02.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Login failed for user 'SQLSERVER\myusername'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Please see the screenshot for illustration.

Note: my username is the same reported in the image:

[image]

Comment: [Connect to SQL Server when system administrators are locked out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15). I suspect you have set up your instance as mixed authentication, and not defined *your* Windows Login as an administrator. If you remember what you defined the password for the `sa` account, then log in as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to check.

1. Did you add yourself as an administrator on the server (SQL, not the computer)? Unlikely, at least with the logged on account, as you are failing login. To fix this, you have to add your account. To do this without logging in, you need to do [something like this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11299/how-to-add-sysadmin-to-user-in-sql-server-2008-when-no-sysadmin-accounts-exist#:%7E:text=log%20into%20the%20server%20as,to%20sysadmin%20fixed%20server%20role) - This is 2008, but the concept is still sound. Google for other options?
2. Do you have mixed mode enabled? If so, you can log in with the sa account and password. And, once in, you can add your account to the admin group [like this](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/silk-test/200/en/silktestworkbench-help-en/SILKTEST-7FFBB86A-CREATINGNEWSQLSERVERADMINUSER-TSK.html)

@Larnu has also answered with the Microsoft page. It is a bit harder to read, but has the same advice as the first link in mine.